# How to write reverseorder program in java?

Tags: java

I'm totally new in Java programming , I wonder how may I write program that reads an arbitrary number of positive integers from the keyboard and then prints them in reverse order. The reading stops when the user inputs a negative number. An example of an execution:

```
Enter positive integers. End by giving a negative integer.
Integer 1: 5
Integer 2: 10
Integer 3: 15
Integer 4: 20
Integer 5: -7

Number of positive integers: 4
In reverse order: 20, 15, 10, 5
```

Comment: The effort you put in to your question is equivalent to the effort you will get out of the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: The whole point of the assignment is for **YOU** to figure that out. Go forth, and good luck.

Comment: @Victor, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately my dear friend, Stackoverflow is not a place where you can get ready-made solution to your homework. This is a place where you get **assistance** and **guidance** for your homework, given that you've already tried something on your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get your input inside a `do-while loop` until the loop condition becomes false, means `y` is negative. Since you've got `i` value incremented before your loop condition is false, decrement `i` value by 1 outside loop.

Next, inside the decrementing `for loop`, print your variables in decreasing index of array, so it will be printed in reverse order of input.

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Capt. Jack Sparrow, pirate lord of the seven seas
 */
public class Example {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] x = new int[50];
        int i =0, y;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter new positive integer: ");
             y = s1.nextInt();
             x[i] = y;
             i++;
        }while( y >= 0);
        i--;
        System.out.println("Number of positive integers: "+i);
        System.out.print("In reverse order: ");
        for(int j = i; j >0; j--)
        {
            System.out.print(x[j-1] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: I was disappointed to see you don't write all your answers in-character. :p

Comment: @PaulRichter I'm sorry my friend, I didn't get you.

Comment: Don't worry, nothing important, I was just making a joke. I meant that you wrote this answer in the style of Jack Sparrow, and so I went looking at some of your other answers, hoping to see whether you always write your answers like this. But, it looks like you usually write normally, so I was simply joking about not seeing what I hoped to see. :p

Comment: Aye, that was *before* I became Capt. Jack Sparrow, my friend. In coming days, you'll know that I'm full of suprises!!! *Drink up me hearties , yo ho!* :D :D (disclaimer: In real-life, I'm nowhere near Jack Sparrow, and I don't drink, because of my faith and culture. :) )

Comment: Please *stop* using pirate speak in your answers. We don't do novelty accounts here. Your answers need to read like works of reference. Write like you're writing a Wikipedia article.

Comment: @meagar Well, people seem to like pirate talk around here. But, if there is a rule of writing wiki answers, then fine.

Comment: I protest. Giving someone a downvote on an accepted answer just because of using pirate English seems very lame. Besides, there isn't actually any rules and regulations in SE about using pirate English. Furthermore, I deserved a formal warning about not using pirate English before getting this downvote. This is outrageous.

Comment: @Capt.JackSparrow Nobody owes you anything before or after downvoting one of your submissions. You don't get to choose which downvotes are valid. While your pirate-talk is awful, I downvoted your answer because you shouldn't have answered this question. It's way too broad for Stack Overflow, and you're not helping anybody by doing this person's work for them. When somebody posts a list of requirements with *no idea* how to accomplish them, that question does not belong here, and it should be closed. You should not spoon feed them the answer.

Comment: In fact, you *told* the person all of this in a comment below their question, and the you went ahead and did their assignment for them anyways. What is this person supposed to learn from this, except that they can copy-paste their homework here and get free and easy answers?